# Translate untranslated words in Drupal

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using calendar module and I noticed when browsing web that some words are not translated (e.g. "prev," "next," "day," "week," "month," "year"). Is it possible to write somewhere the translation for these words?

Answer (score 1):

Content Translation module can help us using Translation Interface (example.com/admin/config/regional/translate/translate) in this regard to search the string and then define a translation against appropriate language.

The strings can only be translated if they are not hard coded and used with `t()` function.

`t()` always searches for appropriate translation with respect to currently selected language otherwise it returns the original string.

Comment: It seems that in Translation Interface there aren't those words. There are only longer sentences (some untranslated) containing them. So, I have to leave it untranslated? It seems strange that such a basic words would be untranslated.

Comment: It is not confirmed but I think string translation is case sensitive. `prev` is not a complete word. other example you showed are lower case. Try a search with first letter capital. do not ignore the case if these untranslated words are not used with `t()` function.

Comment: String translation is not only case sensitive buy whitespace sensitive.  Also, a lot of string use replacement variables, so if you can't find your string try searching for a shorter subset of it!